# Opening a File in C# using FileStream

Tags: c#, binary, hex, filestream

I am trying to open a Binary file that I plan on converting to hex  but I am running into issues with reading the file via FileStream,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFD.Title = "Insert a BIN file";
    openFD.InitialDirectory = "C:"; // Chooses the default location to open the file
    openFD.FileName = " "; // Iniitalizes the File name
    openFD.Filter = "Binary File|*.bin|Text File|*.txt"; // FIlters the types of files allowed to by chosen

    if (openFD.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        chosenFile = openFD.FileName;
        string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(chosenFile); // Returns the directory and the file name to reference the file
        string dirName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(openFD.FileName); // Returns the proper directory with which to refernce the file 
        richTextBox1.Text += dirName;
        richTextBox1.Text += chosenFile;
        FileStream InputBin = new FileStream(
            directoryPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
    }
}
```

I am receiving an error saying that the access to the path is denied, any ideas?

Now that I have gotten that error taken care of I have ran into another Issue, I can read the binary file, but I want to display it as a Hex file, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong but I'm not getting an output in HEX, it seems to be Int values...

```
if (openFD.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {

            chosenFile = openFD.FileName;
            string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(chosenFile); 
            string dirName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(openFD.FileName);
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(chosenFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                size = (int)stream.Length;
                data = new byte[size];
                stream.Read(data, 0, size);
            }

            while (printCount < size)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text += data[printCount];
                printCount++;
            }
```

Comment: if you set a relative path, or hardcode your path, does it work?

Comment: For example, the first 4 bytes from the file when viewed in a Hex Editor are as follows...58 58 58 58, When I do it in my program it outputs 8888888.. Not sure if that helps of not

Comment: @VRKnight if you have a new problem you should ask it separately; your first question was asked and answered and accepted and you will want a separate question to ask/answer/accept as well. You can always include a link to this question in your subsequent one for context, if you think its necessary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code is miscommented

```
string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(chosenFile); // Returns the directory and the file name to reference the file
```

is not the filename, it's the directory path.  You want:

```
FileStream InputBin = new FileStream(chosenFile, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
```

Addtionally, if I were to guess based on your intentions, you should update your full function to be:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFD.Title = "Insert a BIN file";
    openFD.InitialDirectory = "C:"; // Chooses the default location to open the file
    openFD.FileName = " "; // Iniitalizes the File name
    openFD.Filter = "Binary File|*.bin|Text File|*.txt"; // FIlters the types of files allowed to by chosen

    if (openFD.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        chosenFile = openFD.FileName;

        richTextBox1.Text += chosenFile; //You may want to replace this with = unless you mean to append something that is already there.

        FileStream InputBin = new FileStream(chosenFile, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
    }
}
```

Comment: chosenFile = openFD.FileName; richTextBox1.Text += chosenFile; - This appends the directory to the textbox, not the actual file

Comment: I don't understand your question, but [`FileDialog.FileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename.aspx) returns the fully qualified path to the selected file, which includes the directory and filename.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second quesiton:

> I am receiving an error saying that the access to the path is denied,
>   any ideas?
>
> Now that I have gotten that error taken care of I have ran into
>   another Issue, I can read the binary file, but I want to display it as
>   a Hex file, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong but I'm not getting an
>   output in HEX, it seems to be Int values...

Modify to use string.Format:

```
    if (openFD.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
    {

        chosenFile = openFD.FileName;
        string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(chosenFile); 
        string dirName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(openFD.FileName);
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(chosenFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            size = (int)stream.Length;
            data = new byte[size];
            stream.Read(data, 0, size);
        }

        while (printCount < size)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += string.Format( "{0:X} ", data[printCount];
            printCount++;
        }
    }
```

I've included an [ideone example](http://ideone.com/GR8Uv).