# File path not taking correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net

Inside my asp.net website I am trying to access a file

```
 FileStream stream = File.Open("/App_Data/" + FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

I want this code to select an xlsxfile inside my websites app data folder.
This code always take the whole path from directory like

```
'c:\App_Data\w1.xlsx
```

I don't want this code to go for root URL.I just want to take file inside my website.How can i tweek the code to achieve this

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637370/opening-a-file-in-c-sharp-using-filestream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
Server.MapPath('~/App_Data/' + FileName)
```

Answer (score 4):

use `Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + FileName)` instead of `"/App_Data/" + FileName`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
File.Open(Server.MapPath("~") + FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Also check out this answer, it has pretty good explanation of MapPath

[Server.MapPath("."), Server.MapPath("~"), Server.MapPath(@"\"), Server.MapPath("/"). What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath/275791#275791)